# Javascript, frames click and wait for load

Tags: javascript, iframe, bookmarklet

So I'm trying to create a bookmarklet to make my tasks a little bit easier. I can click the button in an iframe, but I need to wait for the iframe to load to get what I need. Here's the last attempt at this:

```
(function()
{
    var els = window.frames["mainFrame"].document.getElementsByName("pcp_PasswordInfoHandler:doShowpassword");

    if(els.length == 0)
    {
        console.log("Button not found");
    }
    else
    {
        els[0].click();

        window.frames["mainFrame"].document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
                var user = window.frames["mainFrame"].document.querySelector("#inp_mlabs_credential_login > div.field-value > div").textContent;;
                var pass = window.frames["mainFrame"].document.querySelector("#inp_mlabs_portal_password_panel_key_password > div.field-value > div").textContent;;
                console.log(user);
                console.log(pass);
            });
    }
}());
```

Comment: Maybe this post helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6183737/dynamically-create-an-iframe-and-attach-onload-event-to-it

Comment: Flyer53 That helped - now have issues with window.open. Works else where... http://pastebin.com/62Adr4Cn